# printf "%n" specifier not working properly

Tags: c, printf, specifier

I copied this code from geeks for geeks.

```c
#include<stdio.h>
  
int main()
{
  int c;
  printf("geeks for %ngeeks ", &c);
  printf("%d", c);
  getchar();
  return 0;
}
```

It should print the characters from start to `%n` followed by the number of printed characters:

[image]

But when I execute it, it's printing this:

[image]

Comment: Check your env, not every env supports `%n`

Comment: i am using clion and mingw

Comment: `clion` is an ide. What compiler?

Comment: What changes if you init your variables? Like `int c=42;`.

Comment: Your code works fine on multiple online compilers. Try using "geeks for %n geeks " instead of "geeks for %ngeeks " and see if there are any noticeable changes.

Comment: if i init 42 (for example) it is printing geeks for 42.

Comment: Worked on `gcc v10.2.0`  under msys2/mingw64

Comment: Coming to OP defense here, my gcc  9.2.0 (tdm64-1) prints 0.

Comment: my gcc version 6.3.0

Comment: i don't know, what do you mean with flag ? i tried compile with gcc main.c -o main.exe && main.exe

Comment: To clarify the previous comment, the value is not assigned to `c`.

Comment: how can i update my gcc to latest version ?

Comment: @AhmetEnesKCC Depends on your environment. In MSYS2 you can use `pacman` package manager

Comment: This [post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61497394/6865932) also has several options, note that you may have to reconfigure your IDE to use the newer compiler.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that the problem lies in the fact that older versions of MingW do not set `__USE_MINGW_ANSI_STDIO` by default, which is not the case for newer versions, what you can do is to manually define it in your program:

```
# define __USE_MINGW_ANSI_STDIO

#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    //...
}
```

Or use it directly on the compilation command:

```
gcc main.c -o main.exe -D __USE_MINGW_ANSI_STDIO
```